# How to set TextFormFieldError outside validator

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `TextFormField()` that checks if the current password the user entered matches their old password. The method which checks if the password the user entered is asynchronous and the `TextFormField()`'s validator function can't be asynchronous. How can I achieve this?

I thought of setting the `TextFormFields()`'s error outside of the widget but I don't know how to do that. I tried using a `TextEditingController()` and a `FocusNode()` none of which worked. I tried Googling but also couldn't find an answer.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using the `InputDecoration()`'s error text parameter.